# Express route 503 error when called from client side in production mode

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am new to nodejs and express and I have a simple express route set up as follow

```js
const express = require("express");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("/api/test", function (request, response) {
  response.send("Hello World!"); // this works when I try from url as www...com/api/test
});

app.get("/api/fetchData", function (req, res) {  // this doesn't work on production 

  fetch(process.env.API_ROUTE, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
      query: `...`   // graphql
    }),
  })
    .then((body) => {
      return body.json();
    })
    .then((data) => res.send(data))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
console.log(`Listening on PORT ${PORT}`);

app.listen(PORT);
```

And I am calling `/api/fetchData` from my client side as

```
useEffect(() => {
 axios
      .get("/api/fetchData")
      .then(...)
  }, []);
```

and it works fine on localhost (with `"proxy": "...:8080"` in my package.json). But when I deploy my app on heroku, api data won't show up. I checked console and network tab, the request url is `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/fetchData` and showing `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)` in my console. I've been trying to fix it but come up with no solutions, am I missing to add something or what am I doing wrong here ?

I also checked the heroku logs and there is one same error in my log but I have no idea how to solve it

`2021-03-28T07:59:59.824758+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/fetchData" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=89d4dd86-890c-4722-9abc-0d058c343073 fwd="210.14.110.62" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it was because I was using `API_ROUTE` as env variable in my local but didn't declare that variable on my heroku platform. But I don't know why request url in network tab is showing `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/fetchData` which is not. I did `heroku config:set API_ROUTE=myurl` on my command and it works fine.

Comment: Awesome. Mark your answer as the correct answer to help out anyone else in the future who might have the same problem!

Comment: Thanks, I will mark it as soon as cooldown is over.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku's H12 error code means the requset took longer than 30 seconds to complete (as stated in their docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout)
Something inside in your logic is taking too much time. Maybe you are trying to access to a resource that is available locally but not in your heroku env?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, in my case it was because of different error.